# SQL Server - how to handle duplicate column names when using PIVOT relational operator

Tags: sql-server

I have an Excel file as a source for my data which looks like this:

```
ColumnName  |Value
----------------------------
OrderNumber |PO-000576632
OrderDate   |2018-09-16
Delivery    |2018-09-22
Currency    |USD
TotalValue  |8006.34
Seller      |SupplierName
GLN         |000098 --this value is dynamic
Buyer       |CustomerName
GLN         |001592 --this value is dynamic
DeliverTo   |DeliveryAddress
GLN         |5940477481122 --this value is dynamic
```

Having the information in this structure, the only way to use further this information in `SQL` is by using `PIVOT` relational operator. I managed somehow to get to the desired output, but since there are 3 `GLN` columns name, I could use only the first one in that list. Is there any way to rename those columns before using them in `PIVOT`?

**Statement**

```
SELECT
      OrderNumber, OrderDate, Delivery,
      Currency, TotalValue, Seller, GLN,
      Buyer, DeliverTo  
FROM
(
SELECT 
      value, columnname
FROM  MyTable
) MyTable
PIVOT
(
MAX(value)
FOR ColumnName IN(    OrderNumber, OrderDate, Delivery,
      Currency, TotalValue, Seller, GLN,
      Buyer, DeliverTo))
piv
```

I did some research and find something promising [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30327357/how-to-remove-rename-a-duplicate-column-in-sql-not-duplicate-rows), but didn't helped me. Any tips would be helpful! Thanks

Comment: Ultimately you're going to need different column names. Could you put the results into a temp table and replace GLN with SellerGLN, BuyerGLN and DeliverToGLN?

Comment: @RichBenner - yes, no problem with that. But how?

Comment: If those values are "dynamic" and you need all of them as separate columns then you need a dynamic pivot script. To avoid duplicate names you may append postfix to such names with `ROW_NUMBER`, for example, before pivoting. If those values are linked to "Seller", "Buyer" and so on as Rich said, then you have a problem - given data does not have strict row numbering, so it's gonna be a problem to determine which GLN belongs whom.

Comment: what version of sql server is this on?

Comment: also, is this a one-time import from excel into sql server or is this a regular thing?

Comment: @RichBenner - 2016. It's not one-time import, but regular and the information within Excel file will always be in the structure I had presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If number of GLN columns is fixed (3), you can use following:

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('OrderNumber', 'PO-000576632'),
    ('OrderDate', '2018-09-16'),
    ('Delivery', '2018-09-22'),
    ('Currency', 'USD'),
    ('TotalValue', '8006.34'),
    ('Seller', 'SupplierName'),
    ('GLN', '000098'),
    ('Buyer', 'CustomerName'),
    ('GLN', '001592'),
    ('DeliverTo', 'DeliveryAddress'),
    ('GLN', '5940477481122')) T(ColumnName,Value)
), Renamed AS
(
    SELECT ColumnName+CASE WHEN N>1 THEN CAST(N as nvarchar(10)) ELSE '' END ColumnName, Value
    FROM (
        SELECT ColumnName,Value,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnName ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) N
        FROM Src
    ) T
)
SELECT * FROM Renamed
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR ColumnName IN(OrderNumber, OrderDate, Delivery, Currency, TotalValue, Seller, GLN, GLN2, GLN3, Buyer, DeliverTo)) piv
```

**Result**

```
OrderNumber     OrderDate       Delivery        Currency        TotalValue      Seller          GLN             GLN2            GLN3            Buyer           DeliverTo
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
PO-000576632    2018-09-16      2018-09-22      USD             8006.34         SupplierName    5940477481122   000098          001592          CustomerName    DeliveryAddress
```

If there are unlimited GLN values, PIVOT clause must be dynamic.

Comment: This would've worked if it was one-time import, but the values will always be different.

Comment: Do you have problem with SQL query or Excel import? Since I don't have your Excel file, I used `Src` as source table. Just remove first CTE section (`Src`), and replace `Src` occurences with `MyTable` used in your example.

Comment: my source table will contain the exact information in my example. So, you are saying to remove `SRC` which also creates `Renamed` as a `CTE` and then use `MyTable`?

Comment: Use `MyTable` in `Renamed` CTE.